# Check if Facebook app is in an iframe tab

Tags: facebook, api, iframe

I need my application to redirect to the site with the `iframe` tab (`https://www.facebook.com/pages/namepage...idapp`) when someone enters the app (`https://apps.facebook.com/idapp`)

How can I check if the app is open in an `iframe` tab?

Answer (score 1):

The a `page` parameter in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) will be present when the app is loaded via a page tab app, and won't be present otherwise.
Use this to determine if the app should render as a canvas app or a page tab app

Answer (score 0):

Set up the canvas page URL in your app settings, and when that URL is called „redirect” the user via JavaScript, `top.location.href = "//facebook.com/yourpageid/…"`

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand. My actual canvas page is www.domain.com/fbapp. How do I know when to call redirect?

Comment: For example by adding a GET parameter to your canvas page URL in your app settings.